# WFS Query filter grouping "and" and "or"

Tags: wfs

I have a WFS query filtering on a property and a spatial element. Exmaple:

```
<wfs:Query typeNames="bag:verblijfsobject" srsName="EPSG:28992">
    <fes:Filter>
        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="false">
            <fes:ValueReference>pandidentificatie</fes:ValueReference>
            <fes:Literal>0310100000665851</fes:Literal>
        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <fes:And>
            <fes:Intersects>
                <fes:ValueReference>bag:geometrie</fes:ValueReference>
                <gml:Polygon gml:id="geo.1" srsName="EPSG:28992">
                    ...
                </gml:Polygon>
            </fes:Intersects>
        </fes:And>
    </fes:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
```

Basically this has the structure:

```
pandidentificatie=0310100000665851
and
bag:geometrie intersects with <gml>
```

How do I expand with multiple geometries so that I get the structure

```
pandidentificatie=0310100000665851
and  ( 
  bag:geometrie intersects with <gml1>
  or
  bag:geometrie intersects with <gml2>
  or
  bag:geometrie intersects with <gml3>
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `OR` operator in exactly the same way as you use `AND` so your query could become:

```
<wfs:Query typeNames="bag:verblijfsobject" srsName="EPSG:28992">
    <fes:Filter>
      <fes:And>
        <fes:PropertyIsEqualTo matchCase="false">
            <fes:ValueReference>pandidentificatie</fes:ValueReference>
            <fes:Literal>0310100000665851</fes:Literal>
        </fes:PropertyIsEqualTo>
        <fes:Or>
            <fes:Intersects>
                <fes:ValueReference>bag:geometrie</fes:ValueReference>
                <gml:Polygon gml:id="geo.1" srsName="EPSG:28992">
                    ...
                </gml:Polygon>
            </fes:Intersects>
            <fes:Intersects>
                <fes:ValueReference>bag:geometrie</fes:ValueReference>
                <gml:Polygon gml:id="geo.122" srsName="EPSG:28992">
                    ...
                </gml:Polygon>
            </fes:Intersects>
            <fes:Intersects>
                <fes:ValueReference>bag:geometrie</fes:ValueReference>
                <gml:Polygon gml:id="geo.2" srsName="EPSG:28992">
                    ...
                </gml:Polygon>
            </fes:Intersects>
           </fes:Or>
        </fes:And>
    </fes:Filter>
</wfs:Query>
```